# Show all lines of a (log) file in terminal

Tags: command-line

With wich command can I get all the lines of a file in my terminal?

`Tail` and `cat` shows me only the last part of the file

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wich` to `which`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a file has too many lines to show in only one screen, you can pipe the output to `less` like so:

```
cat myfile.txt | less
```

This paginates `cat`'s output, allowing you to navigate through the file using the arrow keys.

Comment: UUOC (useless use of cat) :)

Comment: Huh. I'll be that much smarter tomorrow! Thanks for teaching me something I didn't know! :)

Comment: This approach can be used with any command that prints text e.g. `git status | less`

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the size of the file, you can use `tail` (if there are only 10 lines) or `cat` to see the whole log file.

If you want to use a better file viewer for logs on the terminal, I would advise using `less` on a file.

### For Example

`sudo less /var/log/syslog`

This will produce the log file on your terminal screen and you will be able to move around the log file without it passing you like `cat`.

### Advanced `less` features

- To make sure text will stay on the screen after exiting `less` (very useful if you don't have an interface):

`sudo less -X /var/log/syslog`

- To ignore cases on searches through `less`:

`sudo less -i /var/log/syslog`

- To display line numbers when opening a file with `less`:

`sudo less -N /var/log/syslog`

### To learn more about `less`

`man less`

and

`less --help`

Answer (score 1):

You actually can just use less without piping too

```
less myfile.txt
```

More works well too:

```
more myfile.txt
```

The main differences between the two are that more only allows you to go down in a document, whereas less lets you go up and down. The benefit that more has is that is also keeps the information in the terminal when you exit it, which can be very helpful in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `less` command for viewing files with rich extended navigation besides `tail` and `cat`, that only output file content to console.